# Uno.Platform and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uno-platform

I am a C++ and python developer but I need to use C# for a professional project.
I know some good basics of .NET Core but I want to find a good UI library to learn.

I test Avalonia and I want to try Uno.Platform for is multi-platform capabilities.

But, I make simple test on Visual Studio and just try if it works on Windows (with UWP sub solution).
It works (thx for templates and tutorial) when I run the application from Visual Studio.
But I want to try the application directly by executing the App.exe generated in bin/x86/... but nothing append. No trace, no error... just nothing.
I try to deploy but the problem persist....

I probably miss something important but I found no information that can help me on internet.
Did you have information to help?
When kind of topic I don't understand in the C# with Uno.Platform CI?

Answer (score 1):

This seems a pretty general question. The best way to go about it is to go to Uno Platform Discord community and chat with users there - [www.platform.uno/discord](http://www.platform.uno/discord)  - #uno-platform  channel.

For specific questions on how to do X with Uno Platform you should post to Stack Overrlow.

Comment: Okay sorry if my question is too general.
I take of your advice to go in discord. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i will try to answer your question. i am also experimenting with Uno.

Since Uno is Crossplatform, every Operating systems Uses its own "Programm Header"
This Header contains a lot of stuff including the needed Code entrance Point for each OS.
For Windows i tried it with the WPF HOST header and it worked.

If you want to get a executabale for the "Hallo World" example try to publish the WPF HOST Header into a folder. it will contain the .exe

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's work !
But why It's work with skia wof host and not UWP ?